# NodeJs JWT token storing

Tags: node.js

I'm working on creating the user authenticate service and using the passport-jwt-strategy for authentication. but stuck on the point for storing the generated 'JWT token' into the user schema. Is it necessary to store the JWt token into the user model?

Comment: storing token is not necessary because the token itself contains some unique information about user. token can be directly used to get the user information like username. If you want to include the feature of revoking the token then storing token is neccessary

Comment: Okay, But what we can do If we logout the user? In this case, we need to remove the token from the browser local storage only.

Answer (score 1):

JWT are created to be stored on the client side.
The only thing the server should need is a secret key with which to verify the token signature, to make sure it has not been tampered with.
If you need to be able to invalidate session, then maybe another form of validation should be used.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to store jwt token, from server side you just need to verify jwt token, verify auth and roles of jwt token, jwt token should store in client side only. Jwt provides session less authorization to user. For more visit jwt official site.

Answer (score 1):

JWT is stateless and does not need to be stored on the server side. However, the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#page-10) denotes a property `jti` which is the ID of the token. This one might be worth storing to, say, blacklist the one specific token later.